# Elementor de WordPress no me permite editar ciertas páginas

Tags: wordpress, wordpress-plugin, wordpress-theme, elementor

Buenas noches a todos y muchas gracias de antemano por tomarse el tiempo de ayudarme.
Les doy el contexto de esta situación que llevo días sin poder resolver.

Conseguí un tema para aplicar en mi sitio de WordPress e instalé Elementor para editar las páginas, la misma [docu.](http://oceanthemes.net/docs/engitech/how-to-install-plugins-included/) del tema lo enlista como un plugin requerido, entre muchos otros.

Despues de una investigación básica de cómo utilizar el plugin Polylang, lo descargué e Instalé para tener versión español e ingles de mi sitio.
Realicé la configuración inicial de Polylang, definí el idioma ingles para todas las páginas de mi tema y al final termino todo ok. Me propuse entonces comenzar a preparar las traducciones de mi página principal.

- **Home-en.** es el nombre de mi página de inicio en ingles
- **Home-es.** es el nombre de mi página de inicio en español

[image: Mis páginas de inicio en ambos idiomas]
*Mis páginas de inicio en ambos idiomas.*

Ya estaban ambas vinculadas con Polylang y todo parecía estar bien, pero al querer editar mi página Home-es con Elementor, en lugar de abrir el editor de Elementor, me redirigió a mi sitio, indicando que la página no se había encontrado.

[image: Al querer editar mi página principal, soy redireccionado a esta página.]
*Al querer editar mi página principal, soy redireccionado a esta página.*

Esto me sucede al querer editar cualquiera de mis dos páginas de inicio (español o ingles) y un par de páginas más, sin embargo, no es con todas ya que otras sí me permiten entrar a edición con Elementor.

[image: Una de las páginas que sí me permite entrar a edición con Elementor]
*Una de las páginas que sí me permite entrar a edición con Elementor*

He probado diferentes alternativas:

- Aumenté el límite de memoria dedicada a PHP a 256Mb y el problema persistió,
- Desactivé todos mis plugins, a exepción de Elementor y el problema persistió,
- Eliminé la caché de mi navegador y el problema persiste,
- Con ayuda de un compañero seguimos [este post](https://support.weglot.com/article/76-wordpress-404-error-translating) para activar el modo rewrite del servidor y logramos que ya no se nos redirigiera a la plantilla «404 not found», sino a la página en vivo que queremos editar, pero esto como sabrán no solucionó el problema, que es que no podemos entrar al lienzo de edición de Elementor.

En un post de internet vi que activando el modo seguro de Elementor, y ciertamente funcionó. Al querer editar mi pagina de inicio ya puedo acceder a su edición pero, ya que me desactiva los plugins, si guardo cambios la página se actualiza con muchos elementos faltantes que le proporcionaban los plugins que se desahibilitaron en modo seguro.
Se que esta no es la solución, ya que el deber ser es que pueda ingresar a editar la página sin problemas, no se si sea algo que olvidé configurar ¿ustedes qué opinan?

Leí en la [documentación del Debugging Safe Mode de Elementor](https://elementor.com/help/debugging-safe-mode/?utm_source=safe-mode&utm_medium=wp-dash&utm_campaign=learn) un par de pasos a dar, uno de ellos meciona que puede ser el tema el problema, pero si otras páginas sí cargan, se descarta la posibilidad, cierto? además, ya que en modo seguro sí puedo entrar a la edición de mis páginas principales, el problema debe de ser un plugin no es así? Sabrán si Elementor tiene plugins propios que no se desactivan desde el listado de plugins de WordPress?

Por favor, díganme si requieren más información y con mucho gusto se las facilitaré, muchas gracias de nuevo por todo su apoyo.

El blog con el que necesito ayuda es [www.ethergymx.com](https://www.ethergymx.com).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Listo, la solución estaba super cerca jaja.

Simplemente hay que ir a la **configuración de Elementor**, en la pestaña **Avanzado** y activar la opción **"Cambio de método de carga del editor"**.

[image: Pantalla de configuraciones avanzadas de Elementor]

Despues de eso te diriges a tu lista de páginas y al elegir "Editar con Elementor" voala! ya podrás editarlas!!

[image: Página editable que antes no se podía editar]

¡Gracias a todos! Ojalá les sirva :)